# Copy a range from another spreadsheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I stumbled upon a code here a while ago which works to copy a range from one sheet to another within the same spreadsheet.

```
var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

var url = "#gid=" + newSheet.getSheetId()

var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
source_range = source_sheet.getRange(source_range.getRow(), 1, 1, 3);
source_sheet.getRange("I" + source_range.getRow()).setFormula('=IFERROR(Sheet2!C4," ")')
source_sheet.getRange("K" + source_range.getRow()).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + url + '","Generated Sheet")')
var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("B4");

source_range.copyTo(target_range);
```

The script works as intended but now I want to copy from one spreadsheet to another. And when I set the a sheet from a different spreadsheet as the target sheet, I get the error of source and target must be within the same spreadsheet.

Therefore, is there any workaround for this? I was think maybe using importrange, but how do I specify the URL and that selected range in the source range to be imported using the insert function script. If you can think of any other solution, please do let me know.

Comment: Do you want to just make a copy of the spreadsheet or do you actually want importrange which is for viewing the original source on another workbook? importrange and copying the spreadsheet are two totally different things...

Comment: You can copy the complete sheet from one spreadsheet to another.  Then copy the range that you want to the final destination and delete the sheet.  [copyTo(Spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))

Comment: Not the whole spreadsheet. Just a range. I'm aware it's different but I just thought I could use that method because it seemed like I can't just 'copy' the range.

Comment: @Cooper, That's an interesting idea that I think is workable. Can't believe I didn't think of that. I should give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source_range.copyTo(target_range);`

You're getting this error message because `copyTo()` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) is based on a range AND assumes that the source and target are in the same spreadsheet.

The more straightforward method to copy a range is to use `setValues`, even though there are two spreadsheets and two different sheets. The following script demonstrates this.

---

```
function so5894550501() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sourcesheetname = "sourcesheet";
  var source = ss.getSheetByName(sourcesheetname);

  var targetid = "<insert targetid>";
  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetid);
  var targetsheetname = "targetsheet";
  var target = ts.getSheetByName(targetsheetname);

  var sourceRange = source.getRange(1,1,source.getLastRow(),source.getLastColumn());
  Logger.log("the source range = "+sourceRange.getA1Notation())
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(sourceValues);
  Logger.log(sourceValues.length)


  var targetRange = target.getRange(1,1,source.getLastRow(),source.getLastColumn());
  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);// this works

}
```

Comment: So, even if I only want to copy a range, I need to copy the whole spreadsheet? Because I don't really want to copy the whole thing, just a range from 1st to 3rd column.

Comment: My mistake. I had intended to suggest `setValues()` in the first instance, but I thought it better to stick to the exploring the `copyTo()` method that you were employing.

Comment: Does that mean that I can't copy a range then paste it into a sheet if it's in a different spreadsheet? Because if that is possible, I'd prefer that over using `setValues ()` or `setFunctions()`.

Comment: "Does that mean that I can't copy a range then paste it into a sheet if it's in a different spreadsheet?" Two things spring to mind 1) what do you mean by "copy"?, and 2) why do you 'need' to "copy" a range? Is there a broader issue that isn't necessarily addressed in your question?

Comment: Well, I want to copy a range from a sheet in Spreadsheet 1 and paste it into a sheet in Spreadsheet 2

Comment: okay. I'm sorry; I think I have misunderstood you. And I should have said earlier (in as many words) that I amended my answer and rewrote the script. So, if you want to copy a range from a sheet in one spreadsheet to a sheet in a second spreadsheet, then just use the script shown above as a guide - this is exactly what it does, But if I have haven't done what you want, I apologise, and please describe for me the outcome that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @HMProduction, depending on which range you want to copy (if you don't want all data in a sheet to be copied to another spreadsheet), you would just have to change the parameters used in `getRange` in Tedinoz script, according to the range you want to copy.